# Submitting a form at 3 different times using PHP

Tags: php, forms, cron

Sorry if this is not clear, but ill try my best to make it as clear as possible.

I'v got 2 PHP files, one file called "**Form.php**" which has a form, and the other one is called "**Submit.php**" which is the action for the form.

There will be a field called "***How many times:***" which has the options(**1,2,3**), and another field called "***Every:***" which has the options(**1 Minute, 3 Minutes, 5 Minutes**)

The idea is when the user select (3 Times) and (5 Minutes), the form will submit once every 5 minutes and it will stop when its done submitting 3 times.

Is cron job the way to do it? if so how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use AJAX and Javscript timers.

Comment: @JeremyHarris i don't want the user to sit there for 15 minutes till it finish, i want everything to happen on the server.

Comment: Have you already considered using http://gearman.org/?

Comment: @Reto Thank you for your comment, ill check it out, hopefully its what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There a several simple solutions to your problem.
the simplest way to do it would be with one single cronjob and one database.

For the database I would recommend SQLite,it is faster to implement than mysql because there is simply no setup and easy to handle.

The database handles all the data needed to run your operation, things like: "**How many times:**"  and "**Every:**". And the cronjob runs every minute to check which forms need to be sent.

Of course the **database** needs to handle this "extra" information to work:

1. Id of the form job
2. Info saved in the form
3. Counter to keep how many times the form has been submitted
4. Status of the form (if is it still active or it is done submitting)

At the end you need 4 files:

1. "**Form.php**" --> Collects info and sends it "**Save.php**"
2. "**Save.php**" --> Receives info and Saves it to the database
3. "**Check.php**" --> Runs every minute to check which forms need to be sent and calls "**send.php**" for every form that needs to be sent.
4. "**Send.php**" --> Receives the info and sends it.

All this could be done in one single file but it is up to you.

To send the info from **check.php** to **send.php**, it is simpler to send the form data in the url (catching them with GET) rather than using the POST method.
Finally you must add the cronjob to call the file "**Check.php**" every minute The cronjob needs to be setup only once, via your control panel or manually on your command line.